# Force ajax to work in all browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, browser

I have application with huge ajax. Some times ajax not working properly when user close browser. This happens because there are many 3rd party add on installed in their browser which stop (may be) work ajax properly.

Now I have no control over users, so unable to make users careful about their browser. Now what can i do in this situation. Is there any way to force ajax to work even with bad extension installed in browser?

Following code not work when bad extensions (like ask toolbar,alibaba news ticker etc) installed in browser

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/agent/send_offline',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
       ...
    });
};
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you need to do this sync instead of async?

Comment: because i want to complete the ajax request first and then user able to close browser. Is async:true has any special facility to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on always being able to do an ajax call when the user leaves your page.  That just isn't something you can reliably do in a browser.  It may work sometimes, but is not guaranteed to work in all possible ways that a web page can be closed.

There are some work-arounds:

1. You can maintain a websocket connection from your page to your server and when the user leaves the page, the socket will be automatically closed by the browser and your server will then know the user left the page.
2. You can have your page poll your server every few minutes with a simple ajax call and when the server no longer gets a polling ajax call, then it knows that the page has been closed.

Comment: 1.Websocket not support all browser

2.Do you talking about run cronjob?

Comment: websocket is supported in all modern browsers.  How far back to you have to support?  Plus, the websocket doesn't have to be the only mechanism, just the best mechanism to be used when available.  There is no perfect solution for you that works in every browser ever made.  You need to decide which combination give you the best results. I don't understand what you're asking about a cronjob.  The page would poll the server via a javascript timer.

Comment: I need at least IE7+. Without cron job how would server execute code when browser stop sending request?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam - it depends entirely upon what kind of server it is which you haven't said anything about.  I program servers in node.js and I just set a timer.  Other types of servers might have different mechanisms.  A cronjob could be used, but is probably heavier weight that you want just to check if a client has not checked in.  The best answer would depend upon the server environment and would probably be the subject of a different question targeted at different people with different tags on it.

Comment: Hi I am using jQuery and no idea about node.js. My Web server is apache and as far as i know there is no way to "server push" technology in apache

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by storing cookie in browser to call your page after every miniute  where ajax code is placed. try this angle